# Codeigniter session variable lose its value after ajax request

Tags: codeigniter, session, variables

I have a problem, when I make a AJAX request to retrieve more data a session variable called is_logued which indicates is the current user is logged in the system lose its value.

I have test it with the rest of the page and it is ok, no problems. The problem comes when the ajax request is sent.

I have make a debug in the Session class, but I cannot find anything strange. I make a print_r to the values and the variable is correctly set inside the Session Class. Moreover the values are stored in the database in the CI_SESSIONS table.

Anyone knows what is happening? Is there any process that writes in the session table without using the Session library? It is very strange because only is_logued lose its value. I have check is I do it manually but does not. Nobody calls unset to that variable.

More information

```
public function load_next_links($param)
{
  $this->load->helper('principal_helper');       

  echo "is_logued value  ".$this->session->userdata("is_logued");

  echo get_next_links($param);

  echo "is_logued value ".$this->session->userdata("is_logued");

}
```

In both cases is_logued value has the correct value 1. This function is located in the principal controller. But after the call the database has the value 0. Why?

More data:

I have print the values in the database in the last line of the CodeIgniter.php (core) and the bbdd has the good value! why when I saw the database the value is not the correct? where is this value being changed?

Comment: check `register_globals` should set to off in server configuration

Comment: Hi, it is already off :S